# Fatal error: Call to undefined method User_m::get_by() in C:\xampp\htdocs\cms\application\controllers\admin\user.php on line 10

Tags: php, codeigniter

**I have a problem when i was login i got a error like this "Fatal error: Call to undefined method User_m::get_by() in C:\xampp\htdocs\cms\application\controllers\admin\user.php on line 10"**

*this is my user_m.php modal file*

```
class User_m extends CI_Model{

    protected $_table_name = 'users';
    protected $_order_by = 'name';
    public $rules = array(

        'email' => array(
            'field' => 'email',
            'label' => 'Email',
            'rules' => 'trim|required|valid_email|xss_clean'
            ),

        'password' => array(
            'field' => 'password',
            'label' => 'Password',
            'rules' => 'trim|required'
            )
        );

    public function __construct()
       {
            parent::__construct();

       }

       public function login()
       {
            $user = $this->get_by(array(
                'email' => $this->input->post('email'),
                'password' =>$this->hash($this->input->post('password'))

                ), TRUE);

            if (count($user)) {
                $data = array(
                    'name' => $user->name,
                    'email' => $user->email,
                    'id' => $user->id,
                    'loggedin' => TRUE,
                );
                $this->session->set_userdata($data);
            }
       }

       public function logout()
       {
            $this->session->sess_destroy();
       }

       public function loggedin()
       {
            return (bool) $this->session->userdata('loggedin');
       }

       public function hash($string)
       {
            return hash('sha512', $string . config_item('encryption_key'));
       }
}
```

**this is my view file login.php**

```
<div class="modal-header">
   <h3>Log in</h3>
   <p>Please log in using your credentials</p>
  </div>
  <div class="modal-body">


  <?php echo validation_errors(); ?>
    <?php echo form_open(); ?>
    <table class="table">
        <tr>
            <td>Email</td>
            <td><?php echo form_input('email'); ?></td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td>Password</td>
            <td><?php echo form_password('password'); ?></td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td></td>
            <td><?php echo form_submit('submit', 'Log in', 'class="btn btn-primary"'); ?></td>
        </tr>
    </table>
    <?php echo form_close(); ?>
  </div>
```

**this is my controller user.php**

```
    <?php
class User extends Admin_Controller{
    public function __construct()
    {
        parent::__construct();
    }

    public function index()
    {
        $this->data['users'] = $this->user_m->get_by();
        $this->data['subview'] = 'admin/user/index';
        $this->load->view('admin/_layout_main');
    }

    public function edit($id=NULL)
    {

    }

    public function delete($id)
    {

    }



    public function login()
    {
        $dashboard = 'admin/dashboard';
        $this->user_m->loggedin() == FALSE || redirect($dashboard);
        $rules = $this->user_m->rules;
        $this->form_validation->set_rules($rules);

        if ($this->form_validation->run()==true) {

            if ($this->user_m->login() == TRUE) {
                redirect($dashboard);
            }else{
                $this->session->set_flashdata('error', 'That email and password combination does not exit');
                redirect('admin/user/login', 'refresh');
            }
        }

        $this->data['subview'] = 'admin/user/login';
        $this->load->view('admin/_layout_modal', $this->data);
    }
}
```

Comment: You don't have `get_by()` method in your model, which is precisely pointed by error message. Line `$this->data['users'] = $this->user_m->get_by();` is wrong.

Comment: Your filename should have first letter upper case `C:\xampp\htdocs\cms\application\controllers\admin\User.php` same with model filename

Answer (score 0):

You are using the model, so you should change your syntax to something like this:

```
$this->db->get('*')
->where('email', $email)->where('password', $password);
```

If you are meaning to call this function, you should define it inside the model class and add it to the class it self.

Answer (score -1):

Change this line in your user_m.php modal file:

```
class User_m extends CI_Model{
```

to

```
class User_m extends MY_Model
```